# ECC PHP Library

Tags: php, ecdsa

I've spent days trying to find more information on a specific PHP library with no success:
https://github.com/mdanter/phpecc

Does anyone have information on how to use this? All I want to do is:

1. Generate a private key and public key pair.
2. Get the public key from a given private key.
3. Verify signed messages.

Basically, the PHP equivalent of:
http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/sample-ecdsa.html

Comment: I don't know why you say this "off topic" or "minimal effort".  I put in a tremendous amount of work trying to figure this out.